# Kusto Query Specific child records

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer

Is there a way to setup a where clause in Kusto to get specific records with child records

Like if I wanted  Kyle from below

Where address has Code = street and that value= grant AND Code = Number and that value= 55555

```
    {
    "Firstname": "Bob",
    "lastName": "stevens"
    "address": [
        {
            "code": "street",
            "value": "Olsen"
        },
        {
            "code": "Number",
            "value": "123456"
        }
    },
{
    "Firstname": "Kyle",
    "lastName": "richards"
    "address": [
        {
            "code": "street",
            "value": "grant"
        },
        {
            "code": "Number",
            "value": "55555"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try using [`mv-apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator), and filter for records in which the number of conditions met is as expected:

```
datatable(i:int, d:dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic({"Firstname": "Bob",  "lastName": "stevens",  "address": [{ "code": "street", "value": "Olsen" }, { "code": "Number", "value": "123456" }]}),
    2, dynamic({"Firstname": "Kyle", "lastName": "richards", "address": [{ "code": "street", "value": "grant" }, { "code": "Number", "value": "55555"  }]}),
    3, dynamic({"Firstname": "Kyle", "lastName": "richards", "address": [{ "code": "street", "value": "grant" }, { "code": "Number", "value": "11111"  }]})
]
| mv-apply address = d.address on (
    summarize c = countif((address.code == 'street' and address.value == 'grant') or 
                          (address.code == 'Number' and address.value == 55555))
    | where c == 2
)
| project-away c
```

| i | d |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | { "Firstname": "Kyle", "lastName": "richards", "address": [ { "code": "street", "value": "grant" }, { "code": "Number", "value": "55555" } ] } |

**update**: in reply to your comment:

> *I'm trying to do this with a sproc, Would i need to put this into a datatable then query it like that? If so how do I put a query into a datatable*

First, there are no stored procedures in Kusto. there are [stored functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/schema-entities/stored-functions).

Second, if you want to invoke a similar logic over an existing table, you can define a stored function that takes a tabular argument as its input. And, optionally, use the [`invoke` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/invokeoperator).

For example:

```
.create function my_function(T:(d:dynamic)) {
    T
    | mv-apply address = d.address on (
        summarize c = countif((address.code == 'street' and address.value == 'grant') or 
                              (address.code == 'Number' and address.value == 55555))
        | where c == 2
    )
    | project-away c
}
```

```
let my_table = datatable(i:int, d:dynamic)
[
    1, dynamic({"Firstname": "Bob",  "lastName": "stevens",  "address": [{ "code": "street", "value": "Olsen" }, { "code": "Number", "value": "123456" }]}),
    2, dynamic({"Firstname": "Kyle", "lastName": "richards", "address": [{ "code": "street", "value": "grant" }, { "code": "Number", "value": "55555"  }]}),
    3, dynamic({"Firstname": "Kyle", "lastName": "richards", "address": [{ "code": "street", "value": "grant" }, { "code": "Number", "value": "11111"  }]})
];
my_table
| invoke my_function()
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a sproc, Would i need to put this into a datatable then query it like that? If so how do I put a query into a datatable

Comment: please see the **update** section in the answer

Comment: is there a way to pass in a array or list to my_function
Like my_function(value:string){my_table | where address has_all value )
Then pass in 
my_function("grant",55555) and that returns 1 row?

Comment: instead of passing a `string` argument, pass a `dynamic` argument, that holds an array of values

Comment: From the Function itself im tryin to use this
"declare query_parameters(identifiervalue:dynamic); GetTransaction(identifiervalue)"

Trying to send identifierString = '[' + "Bryan" + ']';

but im getting an error
Text=declare query_parameters(identifiervalue:dynamic); GetTransaction(identifiervalue)
SemanticErrors='identifiervalue' invalid query parameter type (expected 'dynamic')

Comment: perhaps it'd make sense to create a new question regarding this, where you can display the specific Nth problem more clearly. piggybacking on the existing thread with N different issues feels less efficient and makes the answers less discoverable to others

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70899348/kusto-stored-function-passing-dynamic-parameter-from-c-sharp-azure-function