# Kusto stored function passing dynamic parameter from C# Azure Function

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer, kusto-explorer, adx

I'm trying to create an Azure Function that queries the adx database.

In my function I have an object that I would like to pass to the stored function in adx as the parameter.

In the function I'm using this in the in the code but getting an error and `SetParameter` only takes a string.

```
queryGetTransaction = "declare query_parameters(ID:dynamic); GetTransaction(ID)";
```

I set that dynamic parameter with `ClientRequestProperties` if "ID" is the object:

```
ClientRequestProperties clientRequestProperties = new ClientRequestProperties();
clientRequestProperties.SetParameter("identifiervalue", ID)
```

I'm getting this error:

> Text=declare query_parameters(ID:dynamic); GetTransaction(ID)
> SemanticErrors='ID' invalid query parameter type (expected 'dynamic)

If I'm not doing this correctly can I pass an object to the stored function and use that for parameters in the where?

```
  private static readonly string queryGetIDs = "declare query_parameters(idvalue:dynamic); GetIds(idvalue)";

   public async Task<List<ID>> GetIDs(ID ids)
    {
        IDataReader reader = null;
       
        var serviceUri = URL To ADX ;
        var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(serviceUri).WithAadSystemManagedIdentity();

        var client = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslQueryProvider(kustoConnectionStringBuilder);

        ClientRequestProperties clientRequestProperties = new ClientRequestProperties();
        clientRequestProperties.SetParameter("idvalue", ids);

        reader = await client.ExecuteQueryAsync("TableName", queryGetIDs, clientRequestProperties);
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a code for a better understanding.

Comment: Updated code above

Answer (score 0):

I got this working

```
string str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ids);

ClientRequestProperties clientRequestProperties = new ClientRequestProperties();
 clientRequestProperties.SetParameter("value", str);
```

The declare query_parameters doesnt have to match the actual stored function in ADX.
I ended up setting declare query_parameters to string and the stored function has dynamic. That fixed the issue.

Comment: Can you highlight what changed, and explain why that was necessary, to aid future readers in better understanding similar types of issues?

Comment: updated my answer